# Генерация фейкового номера телефона

Tags: php, api, lib

подскажите библиотеку или API которые смогут сгенерировать фейковый номер телефона для конкретной страны.

Comment: попробуйте https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker

Comment: Для этого есть поисковые системы, задавать такое здесь неразумно, ставлю минус на ваш вопрос и голосую за удаление.